# Adding and Finding node in LinkedList C

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I have a small bug somewhere, was hoping someone with a little more C knowledge than I have to run through it real quick.

Im not certain if something is wrong in the map_put method or the map_get method, but I can only seem to map_get the first object in my list!?

anyhelp would be appreciated! thanks!

```
//----------------main---------------
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "map.h"
#include "map.c"

int main(){
map_t* newList = malloc(sizeof(map_t));

const char* passString ="a";
const char* secondString="2";
map_put(newList,"1","45");
map_put(newList,"3","3");
map_put(newList,"7","34");
map_put(newList,"a","45");
map_put(newList,"f","45");
map_put(newList,"2","45");



map_put(newList,passString,secondString);
map_get(newList, "3");
//printf("%d\n", map_size(newList));



printf("%1s\n", map_get(newList, "3"));
printf("%1s\n", map_get(newList, "1"));
printf("%1s\n", map_get(newList, "2"));
}





    -----------------map.c----------------------
#include <assert.h>
#include "map.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int bool;
enum { false, true };
int size;

void map_init(map_t* self)

{

  if(self==NULL)
    self = (map_t*)malloc(sizeof(map_t));
  self->entry = NULL;
 self->size = 0;
}
int map_put(map_t* self, const char* key, const char* val)
{
  assert(self != NULL);

  //Create The Node Here For Storing Info;
   struct _map_entry *node =  (struct _map_entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct _map_entry));
   node->key = (char *)key;
   node->value = (char *)val;
   node->next = NULL;
   if(self==NULL)
   {
      map_init(self);
      self->entry = node;
     self->size = 1;
  }
  else
  {
     struct _map_entry *TempNode =  self->entry;
      if(TempNode==NULL)
      {
            TempNode = node;
            self->entry = TempNode;
            self->size =  1;
       }
      else
      {
            bool KeyExist = false;
            while(TempNode->next != NULL)
            {
                if(strcmp(TempNode->key,node->key)==0)
                {
                      KeyExist = true;
                      TempNode->value = node->value;
                      break;
                }
                TempNode = TempNode->next;
            }
            if(KeyExist)
            {
                return "Already Exists";
            }
            TempNode ->next = node;
            self->size = self->size + 1;

       }
     }
}



const char* map_get(map_t* self, const char* key)
{

  assert(self != NULL);
  if(self==NULL)
    return "";

  struct _map_entry *StartNode =   self->entry;
   while(StartNode != NULL)
  {
     if(strcmp(StartNode->key,key)==0){
       return StartNode->value;
   }
   else
    StartNode = StartNode->next;     

  }


    return "";

}

int map_size(map_t* self)
{
  assert(self != NULL);
  if(self==NULL)
    return 0;
  else
      return size;

}

int map_remove(map_t* self, const char* key)
{
     assert(self != NULL);
      if(self==NULL)
        return 0;

      int totalRemovedNode = 0;

      struct _map_entry *StartNode =   self->entry;
      struct _map_entry *TempNode =   NULL;
      while(StartNode != NULL)
      {
         if(strcmp(StartNode->key,key)==0)
         {
           struct _map_entry *Node = StartNode->next;
           free(StartNode);
           StartNode = TempNode;
         TempNode = StartNode;
           TempNode->next = Node;
           size = size - 1;
           totalRemovedNode = totalRemovedNode + 1;
         }
         StartNode = StartNode->next;   
    size = size - totalRemovedNode;  
      }
      return totalRemovedNode;
}


void map_destroy(map_t* self)
{
    assert(self != NULL);

  struct _map_entry *StartNode =   self->entry;
  struct _map_entry *TempNode =   NULL;
  while(StartNode != NULL)
  {
     TempNode = StartNode->next;
     free(StartNode);
     StartNode = TempNode;

  }
  self->size = 0;
  self->entry = NULL;
  free(self);

}


int map_deserialize(map_t* self, FILE* stream)
{
    assert(self != NULL);
    assert(stream != NULL);
    self->entry = NULL;
    if(stream == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
  // error
    } else {

        char *line = malloc(1024);

        while(fgets(line,1024,stream))
        {

            char *value = strstr(line,":");

            int keylength = value - line;

            char *key = malloc(sizeof(keylength));

            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < keylength; i++)
            {
                key[i] = line[i];
            }
            key[keylength] = '\0';
            value++;
            map_put(self,key,value);
        }

    }
    fclose(stream);
    return self->size;
}


int map_serialize(map_t* self, FILE* stream)
{
  assert(self != NULL);
  assert(stream != NULL);


    if(stream == NULL)
    {
      return 0;
    }

  struct _map_entry *it = self->entry;

    while (it != NULL)
    {
        fwrite (it->key, sizeof (it->key), 1, stream);
        fwrite (":", 1, 1, stream);
        fwrite (it->value, sizeof (it->value), 1, stream);
        fwrite ("\r\n", 2, 1, stream);
        it = it->next;
    }
    return self->size;

}

    ----------------------map.h---------------------------

    #ifndef __A1_MAP_H__
    #define __A1_MAP_H__
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef struct _map_entry map_entry_t;
    struct _map_entry {
      char* key;
      char* value;
      map_entry_t* next;
    };

    typedef struct _map {
      map_entry_t* entry;
      int size;
    } map_t;

    // Part one functions.
    void map_init(map_t*);
    int map_put(map_t*, const char*, const char*);
    const char* map_get(map_t*, const char*);
    int map_remove(map_t*, const char*);
    int map_size(map_t*);
    void map_destroy(map_t*);

    // Part two functions. 
    int map_serialize(map_t*, FILE*);
    int map_deserialize(map_t*, FILE*);

    #endif
    ---------------------------
```

Comment: SO is not a substitute for a debugger. Learn to use yours.

Comment: I wouldn't have come for external help if i knew what I what I was doing.

Comment: what is the output it shows,

Comment: Who said you know what you're doing? What I said was that you need to *learn* to use your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

#### General Notes

According to 9899:2011 section 7.1.3 Reserved Identifiers, "*all identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use*". The same section of the C standard also says "*All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces*".

Please note that "reserved" means "you aren't allowed to do it". This means that when you `#define __A1_MAP_H__`, you are treading on namespace that doesn't belong to you, which is always considered to be *inadvisable*. Similarly, your `struct _map_entry` and your `struct _map` are also treading on reserved namespace. Consider renaming all these symbols.

You should not be casting the value that is returned by the `malloc()` function. You do this, inconsistently.

You should not be using the `assert()` macro for normal error checking. The `assert()` function is for debug-level sanity checks during the development process, that can be safely excluded from the code in production builds.

#### map_init()

Your `map_init()` function is wrong. If you pass a `NULL` to the `map_init()` function it allocates storage for one `map_t`, and initializes it, but doesn't have any way of returning it to the caller, so that storage is leaked (lost) as soon as the function returns, and the caller doesn't get anything. You should rewrite this function either to require a valid object be passed to it, or to allow it to return a pointer to a newly allocated object.

#### map_put()

You declare and define the `map_put()` function as returning a value of type `int`, but the only code path that returns anything at all, returns a `char *`.
Additionally, this function doesn't copy the strings that are passed to it, but you're passing it both string literals and strings that are allocated using `malloc()`.

#### map_get()

**HINT**: What does this function return if the first node is a match? If the second node is a match? If no node is a match?

#### map_size()

Why is the function returning the value of a file-scope variable that is never properly initialized? Did you perhaps intend, instead, for it to return the value of one of the elements of the `map_t` structure?

#### map_remove()

This function is so seriously messed up, that all I can advise you to do is go back to whatever reference you're learning about linked lists from, and re-read it.

#### map_destroy()

You aren't `free()`ing the strings attached to each node. You can't, of course, because you aren't copying them in, in `map_put()`, but some of what you put in there was allocated with `malloc()`, so you're leaking memory here.

#### map_deserialize()

This function does an odd half-init of the `map_t` that's passed to it, and it does it before validating prerequisites.
You allocate storage for `line` only once, using `malloc()`, then proceed to pass pointers into the middle of that storage to `map_put()`, which just stores the pointers instead of copying them, so you're overwriting the `value` every time you read the next line.
You `malloc()` storage for `key` each time through the loop, but you're allocating one byte fewer than you need, so you're constantly writing into storage that you don't own, every time you null-terminate that key you've just copied.

#### map_serialize()

**HINT**: If you have a `char *foo`, what is `sizeof(foo)`? How does this differ from `strlen(foo)`?